# Does true equal to 1 and false equal to 0?

Tags: c++, c, boolean

I was wondering, does `true` equal to 1 and `false` equal to 0 and how?

Answer (score 136):

`false == 0` and `true = !false`. I.e. anything that is not zero and can be converted to a boolean is not `false`, thus it *must* be `true`. Some examples to clarify:

```
if(0)          // false
if(1)          // true
if(2)          // true

if(0 == false) // true
if(0 == true)  // false

if(1 == false) // false
if(1 == true)  // true

if(2 == false) // false
if(2 == true)  // false

cout << false  // 0
cout << true   // 1
```

`true` is equal to `1`, but any  non-zero `int` *evaluates* to `true` but is not *equal* to `true` except `1`.

Comment: `true == 1`.  Other non-zero values are true, but are not `true`.

Comment: @dan No, that doesn't even make sense. You basically just said `true != true`. What I think you mean to say is `true == 2` but `(int)true != 2`. `true` is not an `int` just because it can be casted to one.

Comment: No, he's right. I'll make the implicit conversions clear. `int(true)==1`, and `bool(2)==true`, but `2 != int(true)`.

Comment: I see what you're saying, updated answer to make it clear the difference between _evaluating_ to `true` and being _equal_ to `true`.

Comment: 2 is true as well?That means any non-zero is true?

Comment: @user6288471 Yeah, that's true.

Answer (score -1):

Yes that is correct.  "Boolean variables only have two possible values: true (1) and false (0)."
[cpp tutorial on boolean values](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/26-boolean-values/)

Comment: bool does NOT have an integral value.
C++ mandates that when converting bool to integral types `true` evaluates to `1` and false evaluates to `0`, and from integral/float types it says that a zero-Value, soo `0` and `-0` evaluate to `false`, all other values evaluàte to `true`.


`bool`is an integral type but not an integer.
Internally a compiler might decide to use the value 3 for `false` and `64` for true as the standard does not place any restrictions on its internal representation.