# Logical Operators in C

Tags: c, logical-operators

I am having trouble trying to understand how logical operators work in C. I already understand how the bit-level operators work, and I also know that logical operators treat nonzero arguments as representing TRUE and zero arguments as representing FALSE

But say we have 0x65 && 0x55. I do not understand why and how this operations gives 0x01.

I tried to convert it to binary, but I cannot figure out how it works

Comment: Because 0x65 is not 0, neither is 0x55, && is a logical and : true and true is true so the answer is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` is a logical `AND` (as opposed to `&`, which is a *bitwise* `AND`). It cares only that its operands as zero/non-zero values. Zeros are considered `false`, while non-zeros are treated as `true`.

In your case, both operands are non-zero, hence they are treated as `true`, resulting in a result that is `true` as well. C represents `true` as `1`, explaining the overall result of your operation.

If you change the operation to `&`, you would get a bitwise operation. `0x65 & 0x55` will give you a result of `0x45`.

Answer (score 2):

`&&` operator:

If the left operand and the right operand are both different than `0` it evaluates to `1` otherwise it evaluates to `0`.

If the left operand is `0`, the right operand is not evaluated and the result is `0`.

`0x65 && 0x55` is evaluated to `1`.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid *(C99, 6.5.13p3) "The && operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0."*

Comment: Aha! I'll delete my own answer then!

Answer (score 0):

`&&` is a logical operator, not a bitwise operator.  Both 0x65 and 0x55 are true, so the result is a true number.  0x01 is a true number.

Binary representations only come into play for bitwise operations.  The expression `0x65 & 0x55` is equal to `0x45`.

Answer (score 0):

Any expression that evaluates to 0 is false. And any expression that is non-zero is true. So both 0x65 and 0x55 are true.

0x65 && 0x55

=> true && true
=> true

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to convert it to binary

That might have got in the way of understanding. The exact bit-patterns of `0x65` and `0x55` are completely irrelevant to the required result, all that matters is that they're both non-zero. You could consider `a = (0x65 && 0x55)` to be equivalent to something like:

```
if (0x65 != 0) goto condition_false;
if (0x55 != 0) goto condition_false;
a = 1;
goto condition_end;
condition_false:
a = 0;
condition_end:
```

A given implementation might be able to emit code more efficient than that (although I have seen pretty much that code emitted, with each `if ... goto` being a test and branch in the assembly). The more-efficient code might involve some bit operations to avoid branches. For that matter, in this example involving constants the compiler would probably just emit `a = 1;`.

The *meaning* of the `&&` operator is in terms of conditional execution, though. For example if you write `f() && g()` then it is guaranteed that when `f` returns a false value, `g` is not called. If it's possible to get the same result by bit-twiddling then that's likely a bonus for performance.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ has three [logical operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators): logical not(`!`), logical and(`&&`) and logical or(`||`). For logical operators, `0` is false and [anything that is not zero is true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189081). This [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) illustrates how each logical operator works(will be using `1` for `true`):

```
p     q     p && q    p || q
=     =     ======    ======
1     1       1         1
1     0       0         1
0     1       0         1
0     0       0         0
```

The truth table for `!` is as follows:

```
p    !p
=    ===
1     0
0     1
```

For your specific case:

```
0x65 && 0x55
```

Since both operands `0x65` and `0x55` evaluate to `true` the whole expression evaluates to `true` and thus [expands to `1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369783/1708801), which applies to `c99` but other answers in the linked thread explain how it applies before `c99` as well.

Answer (score -1):

C defines values greater than zero to be "True". As both 0x65 and 0x55 match this condition, the result is also True - which, on output, is 1 - or, in hex notation, 0x01.

An alternative style of writing for your code would be:

return (0x65 is true) and (0x55 is true);

Answer (score -1):

As you said the logical operators treat nonzero arguments as representing

```
 (0x65 && 0x55) is equal as (0x65 > 0) && (0x55 > 0)

 0x65 > 0 get true and 0x55 > 0 get true as well

 So (0x65 && 0x55)  is equal true && true = 1
```