# How || and && works

Tags: c++, c, variable-assignment

```
main( ) {
    int   i = 4, j = -1, k = 0, w, x, y, z ;
    w = i || j || k ;
    x = i && j && k ;
    y = i || j && k ;
    z = i && j || k ;
    printf ( "\nw = %d x = %d y = %d z = %d", w, x, y, z ) ;
}
```

I'm just learning C and I came across this code. I honestly dont know what w, x, y and z are assigned to. Apparently the output is as follows:

```
w = 1 x = 0 y = 1 z = 1
```

How is 'w' equal to 1? I dont get it.

Comment: This previous post on logical operators may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332316/logical-operators-in-c

Comment: It means you shouldn't hire the person who wrote that - or if it's a job interview, you should look elsewhere... ;)

Comment: `+1` for your *honestly dont know ...*; `-1` for not making any effort to figure it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You will find this place full of very helpful people. They are especially good at questions like, "I've tried this and this bit doesn't work, what have I missed" ... how about posting where you've looked for an answer, and what you have learned from the reference site, and what bit you haven't quite got yet ...

Comment: @sentrlhack: What does your favorite book on C say about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`||` is the logical OR operator.  From C11 *s6.5.14 Logical OR operator*

> The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.
>
> ...the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;

Applying this to the calculation for `w` we get

```
w = i || j || k  == (i || j) || k
                 == (non-zero || non-zero) || 0
                 == 1 || 0
                 == 1
```

Calculations for `x`, `y`, `z` are similar.  C11 *s6.5.13.3* states that the result from the `&&` operator shall be 0 or 1.

Comment: +1 for explaining how the operators are evaluated, useful information for sure, especially for writing conditions

Answer (score 6):

In C there is no "strong" built-in type for Boolean values, so integers are used instead. Results of evaluating logical expressions, such as ones using `||` and `&&`, can be assigned to integer variables.

When a value is used in a logical operator, the Boolean interpretation is very straightforward: zeros are interpreted as `false`, while all non-zero values are interpreted as `true`.

Now you should be able to figure out the expressions for yourself:

- `i || j || k` evaluates as `1`, because `i` and `j` are not zeros
- `i && j && k` evaluates as `0`, because `k` is zero,
- ...and so on.

Answer (score 5):

This is how conceptually it works:

w = i || j || k;

w = **4 || -1** || 0; //values replaced

w = **true || 0;** //4 || -1 evaluates to true

w = (true); //true is being assigned to integer

w = 1; //0 is false, 1 is for true

Answer (score 2):

`||` is the logical **OR**.

```
w = i || j || k;
```

is equivalent to:

```
w = (i != 0) || (j != 0) || (k != 0);
```

`i` is 4, which explains that `w` is true (which is evaluated to 1 as C uses integers to deal with booleans).

The same is applicable to `&&` (the logical **AND**), etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is logical operations.

|| - means logical or, if at least one element is not 0, result is 1, otherwise its 0;
&& - means logical and, if all elements are 1, result is 1, otherwise its 0;

Logical and has higher priority, so:

```
x = 0 || 4 && 0;
```

Would be 0, because:

1. 4&&0 = 0
2. 0||0 = 0.

These operators are about full value of number. There are | and & operators connected with bits.
Everything about working and priority is the same, just short example:

```
uint8_t x = 2 || 4 && 7;



1. 4=00000100 and 7=00000111
      00000100
   &  00000111
gives:00000100
 2. 2=00000010
      00000010
   |  00000100
gives:00000110, it is 6
```

I hope it is helpful.