# C Programming: Why does (0 || -1) == 1?

Tags: c, if-statement, integer

I am having trouble understanding why the following code:

```
0 || -1
```

Evaluates to `1`? More specifically, I am confused as to what the || and && operators mean when applied to integers.

Comment: because any non-zero is `true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How || and && works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348622/how-and-works)

Comment: Relevant: the spec links in kennytm’s answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291681/does-the-c-standard-explicitly-indicate-truth-value-as-0-or-1

Comment: `||` will give `0` if both operands equal `0`  ; otherwise will give `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every expression `value != 0` evaluates to `1`, if `value` is not equal to zero. (see comment from @MiCo and @M.M.)

`||` is an or operation with two operands. If the left or the right operand is not zero the or operation evaluates to `1`.

Since `-1` is not `0` it evaluates to `1`,

Comment: Since there is actually no true value in C, I would better say that every value !=0 evaluates to 1.

Comment: @MiCo Well that is not true either. `3` for example doesn't evaluate to `1` . (nor does it evaluate to `true`), it evaluates to `3`

Comment: OK, you are right. To be more precise I meant it like this: every expression (value!=0) evaluates to 1, if value is not zero, for example (3 != 0) evaluates to 1.

Comment: @MiCo C has had `_Bool` for 20 years.  Yes C has a _true_ value.