# What do these operators do in C

Tags: c, operators

I'm very new to C and I'm going through some example code and I'm not sure what these operators in the if statements are "asking", so to say.

Here is the code:

```
int main(void){

    int a = 99;

    int b = 0;

    int c = 74;

    if( a || b )
      printf("first\n");

    else
      printf("second\n");

    if( a && c )
      printf("third\n");

    else
      printf("fourth\n");

    if( !a )
      printf("fifth\n");

    else
      printf("sixth\n");

    if( (a && b) || c )
      printf("seventh\n");

    else
      printf("eighth\n");

    if( !c || !b )
      printf("nineth\n");

    else
      printf("tenth\n");
}
```

I know what the operators mean, I just don't understand what is going on when they're going through the "if" statements. Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: If you know what the operators mean, then you know they have a truth value, right? And an `if` statement will check the truth value and, if it's true, execute the following statement or block. (NOTE: A number in C has a truth value of "true" if it's non-zero, and "false" if it's zero.)

Comment: These are boolean operators . I suggest writing a small application to play with the different expressions and different input values

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has done no basic research

Comment: You don't know what they mean if you don't know what they are doing...

Comment: @mbratch Right, but if the statement is if(a || b) what is it asking? All I'm seeing is "if a or b" I don't understand the full extent of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logical Operators in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332316/logical-operators-in-c)

Comment: You said you know what the operators mean. What does `||` mean? Then apply that logic to the values of `a` and `b` based upon what I said previously.

Comment: @mbratch It means "or", I figured it out now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to answering this question is realization of how C treats integers that participate in logical operations:

- Zero is treated as `FALSE`
- All values other than zero are treated as `TRUE`

Here are the truth tables for the three operators from your code snippet:

```
!FALSE -> TRUE
!TRUE  -> FALSE

FALSE || FALSE -> FALSE
FALSE || TRUE  -> TRUE
TRUE  || FALSE -> TRUE
TRUE  || TRUE  -> TRUE

FALSE && FALSE -> FALSE
FALSE && TRUE  -> FALSE
TRUE  && FALSE -> FALSE
TRUE  && TRUE  -> TRUE
```

When multiple operators are used in an expression without parentheses, unary `!` is applied ahead of the binary `&&` or `||`.

Now you have enough information to figure out the output yourself.

Comment: How do I know whether they're True or False?

Comment: See the two bullet points at the top of the answer :-)

Comment: I was about to edit my comment after I reread your answer. Thank you! That is what I was asking! :D

Answer (score 0):

They are just normal operators:

```
|| = or
&& = and
! = not
```

So...

```
if( a || b )
  printf("first\n");
```

Is saying...

```
if a or b then print "first"
```

And...

```
if ( !a )
```

Is...

```
if not a
```

Equivalent to:

```
if a is equal to 0 or NULL
```

Really basic stuff!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to learn about boolean operators if you are working with variables of type bool. I find boolean checks to be less useful when dealing with ints since it's less common to  think of a number as being true or false. With ints you typically consider their numerical values which makes less sense in boolean logic