# right shift division for negative numbers

Tags: integer-division

In case of unsigned integer `u`, we can easily get quotient with `u>>k`(k means divide by 2^k)

But in case of negative numbers, it should be computed as `(u+(1<<k)-1)>>k`

I can see that `u>>k` does not work for negative numbers.

But I am curious why we exactly have to add `(1<<k)-1` to `u`

Any explanations might really be helpful.

Comment: In most programming languages, integer division is defined to round towards zero, while an *arithmetic* right shift rounds towards negative infinity.

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746160/how-to-implement-arithmetic-right-shift-in-c