# adjacency list error with list

Tags: c++, adjacency-list

Basically i generated a adj_matrix and i want to make an adj_list from the adj_matrix...However I keep getting an error saying "no match for call..." 
i tried it without aPair i still get the same error i can't seem to figure out what my problem is. Can anyone tell me why list isn't working? the list is at the very end of the code

```
int **gen_random_graph(int n)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int **adj_matrix = new int*[n];
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)   //generating a N x N matrix  based on the # of vertex input
        {
            adj_matrix[i] = new int[n];
        }
     }

    for(int u = 0; u < n; u++)
    {
        for (int v = u; v < n; v++)
        {
            bool edgeOrNot = rand() % 2;   //decide whether it has an edge or not
            adj_matrix[u][v] = adj_matrix[v][u] = edgeOrNot;
            if(adj_matrix[u][v] == true)
            {
                adj_matrix[v][u] = true;
                if(u == v)                            //We can't have i = j in an undirected graph so we set it to false
                {
                    adj_matrix[u][v] = -1;
                }
            }
            else                                        //if adj_matrix[u][v] is false set the symmetry to be false
            {
                adj_matrix[v][u] = adj_matrix[u][v] = -1;
            }
        }

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < n; j++)           //create the N x N with edges and sets the weight between the edge randomly
        {
            if(adj_matrix[i][j] == true)
            {
                    int weight = rand() % 10 + 1;
                    adj_matrix[i][j] = adj_matrix[j][i] = weight;
                    cout << " ( " << i << "," << j << " ) " << "weight: " << adj_matrix[i][j] << endl;
            }
        }
    }



 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    vector<int> adj_list;
    for(int j = i; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(adj_matrix[i][j] > 0)
        {
           int weight = adj_matrix[i][j];
           adj_list.push_back(j);
           cout << adj_list[i] <<  " " << endl;
        }
    }
}
    print(n,adj_matrix);
    return (adj_matrix);
}
```

Comment: Can adj_list be called?

Comment: umm I didn't make a function for adj_list so no i don't think it can be called. basically i generated a adj_matrix    and now from the adj matrix i have to create adj_list

Comment: hmmmm but i just need the weight from adj_matrix[i][j] is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please supply the full error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that adj_list is not callable, so your code there is broken. There are a couple simple solutions to that. Taking a look at [these docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), you may simply either access `listObj.front()` and `listObj.back()` OR you may also just create an iterator using `listObj.begin()` and iterating over the two elements (which may be desirable if you ever decide to put more than two elements in the list). See [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/stllist.html) for a simple example on creating an iterator for a list, in the code snippet right above the summary.

Note, here, your list object which I called `listObj` for simplicity/abstraction would simply be `adj_matrix[i][j]` in that bottom loop. That should fix your syntax error.

Also, aside from the syntax of your code, I don't get why you're trying to push weights to a list, then you're printing out and returning the adjacency matrix. I also don't get why you would use lists of pair objects when it seems like you only want to push integer weights onto it. For that, you can use a simple vector of integers (i.e.: `vector <int> adj_list;`)... or even simpler, you could use a simple array of integers... rather than using a vector of lists of pairs.

EDIT: After running the code locally and taking a look at the values, I realized the issue a bug in the OP's output was simply that he was using "true" in C++ in place of an integer, which was creating a bug, as explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189072/c-bool-question). The OP also has a further design decision to make where adjacency lists are concerned. More on what an adjacency list is, conceptually, found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).

Comment: o that suppose to be (j, weight) i was just testing out if it accept 1 integer instead of 2 but didn't work out

Comment: Oh, so have you figured it out? It looks like it should be fairly straightforward. But let me know how it goes.

Comment: No i honestly can't figure it out it keep givnig me the same error when i use vector < int > it crashing this time tho

Comment: Ok, good to know it crashes. Let's see what's going on. You're using an int**, and you're allocating space for each of the entries by using new once outside of a loop, and once inside the inner loop of a double loop... Are you sure you're initializing your memory correctly?

Comment: Also, do you have gdb or valgrind? Those can be useful tools for debugging code, especially when it crashes and you want to see a backtrace, or if you don't feel like using print statements to see the values of your data inside of loops etc.

Comment: ummm no i dont have any of t hose im a beginner coder xD and i update the code so far it is working without crashing, however not the result i wanted, it giving me 8936353 as my j :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110079/discussion-between-darkflame-and-user3773048).