# Explain the output of this loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

This is a question from a past paper that I am having issues with, the question and output is displayed below but I don't understand how this is achieved. Can someone please explain.

```
int main ()
{
    int a[5] = { 1 }, b[] = { 3, -1, 2, 0, 4 };
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if (!(a[i] = b[i])) // note: = not ==
            break;
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 3
-1
 2
```

Comment: When `b[i]` is 0, then `a[i] = b[i]` is also 0, and `!0` is true, so the if statement's body is executed.

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand how I get the output?

Answer (score 3):

The loop runs *at most* five times and, each time through the loop, it copies `b[i]` to `a[i]`<sup>(a)</sup>. If that copy resulted in a zero being placed into `a[i]`, the condition of the `if` statement will be true and the loop will break. That's because the result of the expression `x = y` is the final value of `x`.

In your case, `(a[i] = b[i])` will be zero or non-zero depending on `b[i]`. If the former, the `!` turns that into a true value and the `if` body runs (the `break` happens). If the latter, you get false from the `!` and the loop continues to run.

That break happens with the fourth element, which is why you only see three output lines.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> You should be aware that this is valid since the size of `b` is implicitly five (you don't explicitly set the size but it's initialised with five elements). The size of `a` is also five because you specified its size with `a[5]`, despite the fact you only explicitly initialised the first element to `1` (the others are implicitly initialised to zero).

Comment: Does this mean that you could output `cout<<x = (expression) <<endl;` and output the value of the expression while assigning it to `x`?

Comment: @JoelTrauger: Almost. I think it that case, precedence would evaluate `(expression) <<endl` *first* and complain bitterly about trying to left shift using `endl`. You can fix this precedence by using `cout << (x = (expression)) << endl;`.

Comment: Probably worth an edit to explain to OP what `int a[5] = { 1 }` initializes `a` to since this is the reason for the early exit and it's not immediately apparent to the uninitiated what's going on with that brace initializer.

Comment: @user4581301, I'll explain it but it's not the reason for the early exit. That's caused solely by the `0` value in `b`.

Comment: Duhhhr.. You're right. Even with the expletive deleted comment I didn't see the single =.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing you need to know to understand that piece of code is that `(a[i] = b[i])` will be evaluated as whatever that's assigned to `a[i]`, so the break will terminate your program when `i` is 3, which is when `b[i]` is 0. This is also supported by the output you pasted.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand the type casting in C++, basically 0 is false when converted to boolean type (You can see a reference from here: [c++ bool question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189072/c-bool-question))

Now the program does a very simple thing for each iteration in the loop:

> Assign `b[i]` to `a[i]` and try to cast this **int**  to **boolean** type (implicit conversion), and see if it is true of false, it prints the integer if it is true, break the loop otherwise

Thus, you can see why the first 3 integer is printed out, as they are assigned to `a[i]`, being covnerted to **boolean**, and turns out they became true (yes, -1 became true as well, all non zero integer will became true when converted to **boolean**)

The 4th number is 0, and similarily it is cast to **boolean** and became false! So the execution breaks out the loop, no more looping, no more printing. (Even if the 5th number is non-zero, as the execution leaves the loop already, it won't be printed)

Comment: Just one nitpick - I think the C++ standard is similar to the C one, in that casting is *always* explicit - the correct term for *implicit* "type morphing" is conversion.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks, edited. I have been calling them by implicit & explicit cast for a long time...everyday I learn something :)