# Using == outside of an if statement?

Tags: c++, c

I've only ever seen "==" being used inside an if statement. So how does "==" work in this context?

```
a = 5;
b = (a == 18 % 13);
```

Comment: it will simply evaluate to a boolean value, so b will contain either 0 or 1 depending on a.

Comment: Your two quotes don't match: `18%13` and `18%3` are not the same.

Comment: @YefimDinitz - I believe b will be zero or nonzero, where b is anything nonzero - but I don't know if C++ forces bool into 0 and 1.

Comment: I'd suggest you dig deeper a bit in some basic C or C++ tutorial, this is very basic.

Comment: @djechlin: in both C and C++, true things are `1` as an integer, not any other value.

Comment: Learn about the concept of expressions. `==` is not some magic that is inherently related to `if`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `b` is a `bool`, you can assign the result of an expression to it. In this case, if the condition `a == 18 % 13` holds, `b` will become `true`, otherwise `false`.

Basically,

```
a == 18 % 13 - would yield b = true or b = 1
```

and

```
a != 18 % 13 - would yield b = false or b = 0
```

depending on the type of `b`.

Comment: **AND**: because `bools` in C++ are represented by `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`, the expression is equivalent to `(0 % 3)`.

Comment: Sorry, typo both of them are supposed to be 13

Comment: @LuchianGrigore ohh, he got me :)

Comment: @kylemorgan49 if it's 13, then true. If it's 3, then false.

Comment: `b` doesn't have to be `bool`. It's the result of the operator `==` (and other relational/comparison operators) and the operator `!` that is of type `bool`. As long as `b` can be assigned a value of type `bool`, it's going to work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
a == 18 % 3
```

is equivalent to

```
a == (18%3)
```

since the modulus operator `%` has higher precedence than the equality operator `==`.

This expression evaluates to `true` or `false` (actually, `true` in this case). So you are assigning the result of that to variable `b`. `b` itself could be a `bool` or anything that can be converted from `bool`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the precedence rules, which C++ has a boatload of. Bottom line: *Never* write code the way presented in the question. My rule: Everyone knows multiplication and division have precedence over addition and subtraction. You don't need parentheses for `a*b+3`, but spaces do help: `a*b + 3`. Parentheses are mandatory for anything else, and that includes `a==18%13`.

Comment: @DavidHammen I agree entirely, and I must admit that I had to look up the rules for this case to be sure of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's break it down..

The question is:

```
a = 5, b=(a==18%13); // What is b?
```

We'll start with the brackets. The %, called the modulus operator, gives you the remainder of dividing the two numbers. So 18/13 gives you 1 remainder 5. So:

```
18%13 = 5;

// so now we have
b=(a==5);
```

now the equivalency operator == can only return true or false,  1 or 0. It's the same as asking if the left operand is equivalent to the right operand. In this case:

```
 5 == 5; returns true or 1;
```

Therefore b = 1;

Answer (score -1):

C and C++ are not *that* high-level. They have no true boolean type (although in C++ and C99 there are typedefs for providing some small-width integer type to act as a boolean), so any nonzero integer, floating-point or pointer value is treated as boolean true and zero as false. As a consequence, logical expressions evaluate to either 1 (true) or 0 (false) and thus can be assigned to an integer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's because there is actually a boolean type in both C and C++. In C its `_Bool` (although that is typedef'd to `bool` in one stdbool.h) and it's `bool` in C++.

Comment: @Alex "They have no true boolean type" <- _Bool & co. are not really booleans, because they're in fact disguised integers.

Comment: Trying to stuff an integer into a C `_Bool` or a C++ `bool` will result in it being truncated down to a 1 or 0. Both boolean types are guarenteed by the standard to always be 1 or 0. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276207/is-c-c-bool-type-always-guaranteed-to-be-0-or-1-when-typecasted-to-int)

Comment: This is wrong; C and C++ both have true boolean types