# if statement integer

Tags: c, if-statement, integer

I think this is a simple question, but I'm struggling with the following. In my example I have the following statement (language is C):

```
int foobar

if (foobar)
{
// do something.
}
```

Now, if I am correct about this, this statement is true when `foobar` is not zero. So it should be much the same as `if (foobar!=0)`.

But what happens if `foobar` becomes a negative number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is C/C++ bool type always guaranteed to be 0 or 1 when typecast'ed to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276207/is-c-c-bool-type-always-guaranteed-to-be-0-or-1-when-typecasted-to-int)

Comment: [What is the boolean value of integers other than 0 or 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27024044/995714), [Is it ok to assume 0 is false and 1 is true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33756721/995714)

Comment: @phuclv How can an older post be a duplicate of a newer?

Comment: @SHR [*The general rule is to keep the question with the best collection of answers, and close the other one as a duplicate*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/230282). Posted time isn't considered here. But the other question was postedi n 2010, how can it be newer than this?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was not closed at the time. OP already understood that the behaviour depends on whether `foobar` is equal to zero or not. So the only remaining question is "are negative numbers equal to zero?" which... is a math question and not a programming question, to the extent that it makes any sense at all (if you can't answer that, then how can you have heard of negative numbers in the first place?).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

negative or positive. Anything that's not a 0 is a true value in `if`

Also, Consider a negative number: -1

-1 in C internally is represented as: `0xFFFFFFFF`, in which case, it would be a positive number if I cast it to unsigned integer.

But after the advent of C99 standard compilers, I suggest you use
`<stdbool.h>` instead. Makes the guessing work a lot less:

[Read here about stdbool.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/stdbool.h.html)

Comment: Representation of negative numbers is implementation-defined. Also it does not matter to this question, only the *value* matters, regardless of how it is represented.  The `int` is not converted to `unsigned int` in this context.

Comment: @M.M technically everything's "Implementation Defined" - unless you plan to implement it for a particular machine. What if I implement a machine that cannot represent Zero? That's why the `<stdbool.h>` :)

Comment: You clearly don't know what "implementation-defined" means.  If there is a machine that can't represent 0, then it cannot have a conforming C compiler  .

Comment: @M.M could you point me in the ISO document where it says "If there is a machine that can't represent 0, then it cannot have a conforming C compiler"

Comment: See C11 5.2.4.2.1/1  . For example, `int` is required to be able to store all values in the range [-32767, +32767]  , which includes 0

Comment: @M.M so that means, for a conforming C compiler, the size of `int` has to be minimum of 2 byte length?

Comment: It has to be minimum of 16-bit length (the size of 1 byte may be more than 8 bit)

Answer (score 6):

same, the

```
if (foobar)
```

means foobar not zero so whether it is positive or negative doesn't matter, it is still not zero

Answer (score 0):

Your statement should return true if foobar is a negative number (it's still different than zero) but you should avoid that sort of test as it's not the best practice to test variables that can have different 'true' values in that way.

Comment: that is just what i'm trying to avoid, that it gets to a unknow state. I saw this line of code in someone elses program and then it hit me. why use that statement instead of if(foobar!=0); now i know. Thanks all for anwsering my question!