# What is the boolean value of integers other than 0 or 1?

Tags: c++, boolean

I was writing a simple function to derive a new filename based on a set of files that should be named as cam1_0.bmp, cam1_1.bmp, and tried this out.

```
static int suffix = 0;
std::string fPre("cam");
std::ifstream fs;
std::string fName;
do {
    fName = fPre;
    fName.append(std::to_string(camera)).append("_").append(std::to_string(suffix)).append(".bmp");
    fs.open(fName);
} while (fs.good() && ++suffix);
```

This works and it made me wonder what is the standard, defined behavior of corresponding boolean values for number values other than 0 or 1. With this experiment I know all values including negative values other than 0 evaluates to true. Is only 0 considered to be false as per the standard?

Comment: Yes. `0` is the only 'falsy' integer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In C++, integers don't have boolean values. (Different languages have different rules, but this question is about C++.)

The result of *converting* an integer value to type `bool` (a conversion which is often done implicitly) is well defined. The result of converting `0` to `bool` is `false`; the result of converting any non-zero value to `bool` is `true`.

The same applies to floating-point values (`0.0` converts to `false`, all other values convert to `true`) and to pointers (a null pointer converts to `false`, all non-null pointer values convert to `true`).

Comment: In addition to the above, it's worth noting that rule "default value of type converts to `false`", although that's so in some other languages, in C++ that's so only for the basic built-in types. In particular, wrt. conversion to `bool` **an empty string** is viewed as the non-null pointer that it decays to, and so it converts to `true`. While in e.g. Python it converts to `False`.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that "integers don't have boolean values".  First off, it's all zeros and ones underneath, so there is no difference as far as the machine is concerned.  Secondly, there are plenty of programming languages that are either weakly-typed and *use numbers as booleans*, such as M[umps]; or that – for better or worse – support implicit conversion from numbers to booleans, such as C; or that simply treat everything as being "truthy" or "falsy", such as JavaScript.

Comment: @Sildoreth: You may disagree if you want, but that's the way the standard was nailed down. And anyway, it does not matter what funky things other languages do.

Comment: @Sildoreth: The question was about C++; that's the context in which I answered. I'm using the word "boolean" specifically to refer to the C++ type `bool`, and "integers" to refer to values of C++ integer types. Values of *any* type, including `bool` are represented as "all ones and zeros", but the question wasn't about the underlying representation. The C++ standard explicitly says that the condition in an `if` or `while` statement is converted to `bool`. (The C standard, for example, doesn't say that; my answer to a similar question tagged "C" would have been quite different.)

Comment: Is it alright to exploit this property and use it as above? Or can this be considered bad practice?

Comment: @dev_nut: It's very common practice. Using the result of `fs.good()` in a Boolean context is of course perfectly acceptable, since it's of type `bool` to begin with. Using an integer value (that might have meaning values other than `0` or `1`) is largely a matter of personal taste. But in this case, `++suffix` isn't really a meaningful part of the condition; it's always at least 1, so it always converts to `true`. I'd probably re-work the logic to move the `++suffix` inside the body of the loop.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to add I want to increment suffix in this context only if fs.good(), and this seemed an acceptable and short way to do it, without adding an if condition.

Answer (score 4):

The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become false. All other values become true.

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Boolean_conversions)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, any number other than 0 is considered as true for boolean.

Visit http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?405047-Classic-VB-Why-is-TRUE-equal-to-1-and-not-1 for some explanation.

Comment: While VB and C++ do behave the same in this case, you shouldn't assume that the behavior of Visual Basic has anything to do with the behavior of C++.