# C++ | Boolean Values, which is true?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iostream

I recently have been reading a tuition book in C++, the question was under a chapter discussing Boolean operators. The question that confused me was as follows:

1. Which of the following is true?

   - A. 1
   - B. 66
   - C. .1
   - D. -1
   - E. All of the above

The answer itself is E according to the paper however, from a newbie perspective like myself, I assumed that A was the answer as a true value is stored as a 1 whereas a false value was stored as a 0? So why would the answer be all of the above?

Comment: It's a poor question but they probably mean: which of these would result in `true` after being converted to `bool`

Comment: Any value other than `0` is considered as `true` in C++.

Comment: I thought that it asks *which of the following answer is true (correct)?*. It took me a while to understand that the question actually asks *which of the following evaluates to true?* [In C++ what causes an assignment to evaluate as true or false when used in a control structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2003895/995714), [What is the boolean value of integers other than 0 or 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27024044/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any value that is not equal to zero is considered `true`. So the answer to the question is *E* since none of the listed values are zero.