# Variable as parameter for if()

Tags: c, if-statement, output

I'm fairly new to coding and had a question regarding the output of a program I've recently encountered. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char x = 16;
    x = x * 16;

    if (x) {
        printf("True.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("False.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is apparently "False.\n". I have two questions regarding this:

1. What does it mean if the argument of a conditional statement is simply a variable?
2. Why is the output "False.\n"?

Thank you! Any word of advice or tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read any basic C book or tutorial. Those are better resources for C fundamentals than Stackoverflow. But in summary, 0 is false in C and anything else is true. And the result is false because `16*16` overflows a `char` and hence the result is 0.

Comment: @kaylum it's `unsigned char`. And out-of-range assignment (not overflow) as the operands of `*` are promoted to `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if statement integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646718/if-statement-integer)

Comment: Try `printf("%d\n", (int)x);` You will find it prints 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unsigned char x = 16;
```

`x` is an `unsigned char`, which is in range `[0, 255]`.

```
x = x * 16;
```

the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)(`§6.2.5/9`) states

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overﬂow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type.

`x` equals `16 * 16 % 256 = 256 % 256 = 0`.

```
if (x) {
```

For values not equal to zero this statement should be `true`.
For values equal to zero this statement should be `false`, and this was your case.

Answer (score 3):

`x * 16` is not overflow.

`x` has the value of 16.  As part of the multiplication, `unsigned x` is converted to `int` and code does an `int * int` whose product is 256 - no overflow.

Now `int 256` is assigned to an `unsigned char`.  When some *unsigned integer* type is assigned a value outside its range, the value is reduced/increased in "max + 1" steps, or 256 until it is in range as the max value of `unsigned char` on OP's platform is 255.  Again, no overflow.  The value is 0.

> What does it mean if the argument of a conditional statement is simply a variable?
>   Why is the output "False.\n"?

The `if(something)` is *false* if `something` equates to 0, all else is *true*.

```
if (x) {
//
if (0) {
//
if (false) {
    ... // irrelevant
} else {
    printf("False.\n");
}
```