# If two functions each return bool, is it safe to use bitwise operators to combine them?

Tags: c, boolean, operators, c99

Suppose I have two functions which may have side effects, and return boolean values. (with `bool` as defined in `<stdbool.h>`, so that defines `bool` as the `_Bool` type)

```
bool tweedledee(MyState *pmystate);
bool tweedledum(MyState *pmystate);
```

Is it safe to use bitwise operators to combine them?

```
bool both_tweedles = tweedledee(&mystate) & tweedledum(&mystate);
```

or

```
bool either_tweedle = tweedledee(&mystate) | tweedledum(&mystate);
```

I would traditionally use the logical operators `&&` or `||`; I'm working on a project where my team members are using the bitwise operators, since the functions may have side effects, and we want both function calls to occur. (The logical operators are [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).)

My only reservation is that I'm not sure whether a function returning `bool` can safely be assumed to return 1 and 0, rather than something else as an alternate value for `true`.

---

Just as an example: what if someone evil implemented them as follows?

```
bool tweedledee(MyState *pmystate)
{
   return 66;
}

bool tweedledum(MyState *pmystate)
{
   return 33;
}
```

then `66 & 33` is 0, and `66 | 33` is 99.

Comment: this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276207/is-c-c-bool-type-always-guaranteed-to-be-0-or-1-when-typecasted-to-int

I think that in c the bool is macro. so the answer is yes you can.

Comment: From the C99 standard: When any scalar value is converted to `_Bool`, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1. `bool` expands to `_Bool` in `<stdbool.h>`: `#define bool _Bool`.

Comment: While the bitwise combination of bools is safe, the order in which the operands are evaluated is unspecified, so one compiler might call tweedledee first and then tweedledum, while another might call tweedledum first.  If they have side effects, that may be important.

Comment: Ooh -- interesting point. Is there a way to cause one to occur before the other? I assume separate statements would do it (vague understanding of [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), but I'm not positive.

Comment: @JasonS You'd have to introduce a sequence point (via one of the mechanisms listed in that wikipedia article).  In this case, you'd have to use separate statements, and at that point you might as well use logical operators instead of bitwise operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From section 6.3.1.2/1 of the C99 standard:

> When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

*If* you're using `stdbool.h`, then `bool` (which is a preprocessor macro defined to be `_Bool`) therefore must be only 0 or 1, your `tweedledee` and `tweedledum` functions cannot return values outside of that range, and using bitwise operations on them should do what you expect.

If, however, `tweedledee` and `tweedledum` are using some other `bool` type that isn't `_Bool`, then all bets are off.

Comment: I still hope C17 (or whenever the next version will be released) adds some non-`#undef`able `#define` to the preprocessor so that any re-definition of vital macros by some ido* will eventually generate an error.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, the safety of the sample that you posted will depend on the compiler/version/platform in use.

A potentially safer implementation for the use of '&' would be something like the following:

```
bool either_tweedle = ( tweedledee(&mystate) != 0 ) & ( tweedledum(&mystate) != 0 );
```

This defends against the possibility of either tweedledee or tweedledum shoving a value other than 0 or 1 into their bool return value.

The '|' case you provided should be perfectly safe.

Comment: If C99 `_Bool` is used (either direct or through `stdbool.h`), the values are _guaranteed_ to be 0 or 1 only.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure whether a function returning
>   bool can safely be assumed to return 1 and 0, rather than something
>   else as an alternate value for true.

**Yes.** You can safely assume this and use bitwise operations.

From C99 (ISO 9899:1999) 7.16.3:

> The remaining three macros are suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing
>   directives. They are:
>
> `true` which expands to the integer constant 1,
>
> `false` which expands to the integer constant 0, and
>
> `__bool_true_false_are_defined` which expands to the integer constant 1.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not talking about whether `true` evaluates to 1. I'm asking whether a function that returns a `bool` can be assumed to evaluate to 1. If I write `bool nasty() { return 8; }` will 8 be cast to 1?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a *safely* assumption that can be made in general. It depends on the code. The only safe way is using the ugly `_Bool` keyword because C99 and C11 have the obsolescent feature allowing the three macros (`bool`, `true` and `false`) to be un- and redefined.

Comment: @cremno: If you are going in that direction, you are lost anyway. macros could even `#define int unsigned` or similar. That's what coding standards are for: to ensure such is not done (among others).

Comment: @Olaf: I see your point. However `bool` is a bit more special than `int` by not being part of K&R C / C90 (people might have defined their own `bool`) and by not being a keyword. I think an answer to this question should mention this (like the current most upvoted does) even if it's unlikely.

Comment: @cremno: "people might have defined their own bool". Yes, that's why I mention coding standards. Also: if they did, you will either get a redefinition error from cpp, or a Syntax error (typedef/enum). There is a point, however, you have to rely on the code you use.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the result of the logical operation as the condition of an if-statement, it is possible that one of the both functions will not be executed at all. If this is not intended, then you'd better save the results in two variables and then do logical operation directly on the result variables.

Comment: Short circuit evaluation is not related to a conditional _statement_, but the boolean operators as OP apparently is very well aware of. That is actually the reason for his question: to avoid this. And it is very well defined by the standard.