# Is there a difference between if (intVar) and if (intVar != 0)?

Tags: c++

I'm interested in knowing if there is a difference between these two if blocks in c ++.
It would be very useful if with the answer you can cite some reference.

```
if ( intVar!= 0 )
{
  //Do something
}
```

and

```
if (intVar)
{
  //Do samething
}
```

Where `intVar`, could be any type of integer variable with any value.

[EDIT] On the subject "duplicated question". I did not find any question about this in which the if statement is involved.

Comment: There's absolutely no difference, whatsoever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is C/C++ bool type always guaranteed to be 0 or 1 when typecast'ed to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276207/is-c-c-bool-type-always-guaranteed-to-be-0-or-1-when-typecasted-to-int)

Comment: I beg to differ with everybody saying 'there is no difference'. There is clearly a difference. The first version is longer than the second by 5 chars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of the expression required in the `if` condition is boolean. The expression `intVar!=0` is already boolean, the expression `intVar` has type `int` and requires an implicit conversion to boolean. As it happens the conversion rules for `int` to `bool` are precisely that anything non-zero maps to `true` and zero maps to `false`, so the resultant expression evaluation is exactly the same.

Sometimes writing the full `intVar!=0` can add clarity (for example, to make it clear you're not evaluating a pointer type for `nullptr` but rather an integral type for zero), whereas other times it doesn't - it really depends on the context.

Regarding requested references, I will use the [standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf). The section relating to conversions [conv.bool]:

> **4.14 Boolean conversions**
>
> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
> prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member
> pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to
> true

Comment: I am beginning to think that this may be the correct answer, but could you cite any reference?

Comment: @Rama Drafts of The Standard are available online. Search for "conversion".

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to other's answers (and for fun), I'd like to say that for an `intVar` of a user-defined type defining an implicit conversion operator to `int` and another to `bool`, the two expression could have a different behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>

class Celcius
{
    int _value;
public:
    Celcius(int value) : _value(value) {}
    operator int() { return _value; }
    operator bool() { return _value > -273; }
};

int main()
{
    Celcius waterBoilingPoint(0);

    if (waterBoilingPoint != 0) { // false
        std::cout << "This is not Standard Conditions for Temperature and Pressure!\n";
    }

    if (waterBoilingPoint) { // true
        std::cout << "This is not 0K (pun intended).\n";
    }
}
```

But this is an edge case I wouldn't jump into.

Comment: Nice! This is the most interesting answer to the most boring question :)

Answer (score 4):

In C++ (and many other languages) there is no difference as any non zero value is "truey" and zero itself is "falsey".