# c++ : Why does assigning true or false to char compiles fine

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, boolean

I am wondering why the following program compiles fine

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   char a = false;
   if (!a) {
       std::cout << "kdjk";
   }
   char b = true;
   if (!b) {
       std::cout << "ppp\n";
   }
   
   return 0;
}
```

**Output** : prints `kdjk`

Why does assignment of bool value to char compiles without warnings?

Comment: It's [implicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). `true` is `1` equals to `SOH`. `false` is `0` equals to `NUL`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276207/is-c-c-bool-type-always-guaranteed-to-be-0-or-1-when-typecasted-to-int

Comment: The _why_ is in part that C++ had been developed with backwards compatibility to C, and in part when the `bool` type was actually added to the language it also used the fairly flexible implicit type conversions prevalent for other types.  This is not a behavior that I like, but it would be a major breaking change to change the rules now, and would break C++'s rather impressive effort to maintain backwards compatibility to earlier C++ standards and C.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
char a = false;
```

invokes an *implicit conversion* from `bool` to `char`. The language rules for converting a `bool` value to an integral type (such as `char`) say that:

> A prvalue of type **`bool`** can be converted to a prvalue of type **`int`**, with
> **`false`** becoming zero and **`true`** becoming one. The result is that the value of `a` is 0 and the value of `b` is 1.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `false` is 0 and that fits into character and `!` is an operator that checks if the operand is 0 or not. That's why it works.

Comment: `false` is not a character.

Comment: @KeithThompson Updated the answer, it's 0 and it fits into the character.