# Special use of operators & and ==

Tags: c

I don't understand the use of the operators & and == in the following piece of code:

```
Static boolean foo(){

    long stat;
    /* ...code*/

    if (!(stat & 1)){
     /* code... */
    }

     return (stat == SOME_MACRO);
 }
```

- What does & do inside the if comparison?
- What does == do inside the
  return ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That isn't really a "special use". They do the same thing they always do.

Comment: May be useful [Bitwise Operation and Usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage)

Answer (score 3):

`&` is a bitwise AND, which is testing whether the least significant bit of `stat` is set.

The `==` makes the function return `1` (meaning "true") if `stat` is equal the value of to `SOME_MACRO`.  Otherwise it returns `0` (meaning "false").

Comment: You shouldn't rely on Boolean true being equal to 1. According to the C standard, any non-zero value evaluates as true. Most compilers will generate 1 for true on a Boolean expression, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Any non-zero value evaluates to true, but I think true always evaluates to 1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725044/can-i-assume-booltrue-int1-for-any-c-compiler

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm: The `==` will only yield 1 or 0 (6.5.9/3).

Comment: @JohnBode: Ah ha, nice spotting. I should've known to check the standard first! =)

Answer (score 1):

`if (state & 1)` is same is `if state is odd`.

`return (stat == SOME_MACRO);` is same as

```
if (state == SOME_MACRO)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Explanation: The binary representation of any odd number would have a 1 at its last digit. For example,

```
3 = 11
5 = 101
7 = 111
```

If you already know what `&` does, you will notice that when you perform `n & 1`, all bits except the last one is set to zero, and the last bit remain unchanged. So `n & 1` returns the last bit of `n`, which is `1` if `n` is odd, and `0` if `n` is even.

And `(state == SOME_MACRO)` will evaluate to `true` if the expression is True, and evaluate to `false` if the expression is False. So it will return either `true` or `false` depending if `state` is equal to `SOME_MACRO` or not.

Answer (score 1):

The & (bitwise AND) operator compares each bit of its first operand to the corresponding bit of the second operand. If both bits are 1's, the corresponding bit of the result is set to 1. Otherwise, it sets the corresponding result bit to 0.

the function will return true if stat equal to SOME_MACRO, false otherwise