# Does boolean true ever return 0?

Tags: c++

I was in a lecture and on the power point slides states that true would return 0 and false would return 1. I stated that in Visual Studio anything non zero is considered true, but is there a C++ standard that defines 0 as true?

Visual studio's results were disregarded as non standard but I doubt that it is.

```
bool tru = true; // returns 0
bool fal = false; // returns 1
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? Can you provide a complete program that reproduces the behavior?

Comment: I was just checking if the lecture's were wrong. The behaviour in Visual Studio 2013 is 1 == true and 0 == false

Comment: Are you sure (s)he was talking about functions return values, and not process exit status?

Comment: There is no return in the example, so it isn't clear what they are referring to.

Comment: In other words, values such as `true` or `false` don't return anything, so the question is meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely not. From the C++14 working draft (chosen here because I was able to find it easily, not because it's specific to C++14):

> A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.

— http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf §4.5.6 (page 85)

Indeed, this behavior is common to most programming languages. Off the top of my head, for instance, Perl, Python, PHP, and Javascript all treat 0 as false and nonzero values as true. The only situation I can think of where 0 is "true" is in UNIX shell scripting, where an exit code of 0 is used for success and nonzero values are used for errors.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and get the lectures corrected

Comment: Every C++ standard - not just C++14 - has specified that converting true to int gives a value 1, and false gives a value 0.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725063/3425536), `true` is defined by the standard to compare equal to `1`, and `false` to `0`:

> (§4.7/4): "If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted to one."