# C++ : "While" keep executed even if the condition isn't true

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int choose, num1, num2, result1, result2;
    cout << "Type '1' for plus, '2' for minus\n";
    cin >> choose;
    if (choose = 1) {
        cout << "Enter the first number :\n";
        cin >> num1;
        cout << "Enter the second number :\n";
        cin >> num2;
        cout << "Here's the result :\n";
        result1 = num1 + num2;
        cout << result1;
    }
    if (choose = 2) {
        cout << "Enter the first number :\n";
        cin >> num1;
        cout << "Enter the second number :\n";
        cin >> num2;
        cout << "Here's the result :\n";
        result2 = num1 + num2;
        cout << result2;
    }
    while (choose != 1 || 2) {
        cout << "You need to type '1' or '2'!\n";
        cin >> choose;
        if (choose = 1) {
            cout << "Enter the first number :\n";
            cin >> num1;
            cout << "Enter the second number :\n";
            cin >> num2;
            cout << "Here's the result :\n";
            result1 = num1 + num2;
            cout << result1;
        }
        if (choose = 2) {
            cout << "Enter the first number :\n";
            cin >> num1;
            cout << "Enter the second number :\n";
            cin >> num2;
            cout << "Here's the result :\n";
            result1 = num1 + num2;
            cout << result2;
        }
    }
}
```

so i'm trying to create a simple calculator by typing 1 for "+" or 2 for "-" but doesn't seems to work, i use "while" so when you type other value it will ask you to type 1 or 2, but when i debug it, it always executed (the "while") even if i type 1 or 2, please help me.

Comment: `while (choose != 1 || 2)` is equal to `while ((choose != 1) || 2 )`. And integer != 0 ist true in c++

Comment: `while (choose != 1 || 2)` - always true because 2 is always true

Comment: `while (choose != 1 || 2)` is equivalent to `while ((choose != 1) || 2)`. Which evaluates to true as `2` is casted to `true`.

Comment: You don't need to change your question title, we can see you've accepted an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your while condition `(choose != 1 || 2)` is equivalent to `((choose != 1) || 2)`. Which evaluates to `true` because an `int` that is different than `0` is true true when casted to bool in c++. You need to change your condition to `while (choose != 1 && choose != 2)`.
Here is a good answer that explains the int to bool: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31551979/4179302

However, that's not the only problem in your code. You should change your `if` statements from `if (choose = 1)` to `if (choose == 1)` because `=` is assigning and `==` is comparing.

Moreover, you can youse `if` and `else if` so if the first is met, the second is not checked.

Comment: +rep very helpful, anyway i learn from SoloLearn and they doesn't explain about these things, thank you so much.

Comment: `choose != 1 || choose != 2` is always true, really you need to change the code to `while (choose != 1 && choose != 2)`

Comment: OMG!! You are so much right!! I've changed the condition.

Answer (score -2):

Try this (choose!=1)||(choose!=2) in place of "choose!=1 || 2 ". The condition inside the if condition, choose=1 should be replaced with choose==1. choose=1 is an assignment whereas choose==1 is comparison.