# Does while loop consider zero 0 as a False Condition

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a Question About While Loop.

```
int space = 4;
while(space){
    cout<< "*";
    space --;
}
```

This While Loop will run 4 times and stop when value reaches to Zero 0, So my Question is we do not specify any condition like while(space > 0){...} then why it Stop.

Or this Zero 0 consider as False , and first our while loop is true and when Reaches to 0 it becomes False and Stop.

Please Tell me , i am little confused about it.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow make that an answer.

Comment: Take a look at [implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) or this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551888/casting-int-to-bool-in-c-c .

Answer (score 2):

`int` gets converted to `bool` in a boolean context using space != 0.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop takes a condition which is a `bool`. In this case, you've passed in an `int` instead, which will get implicitly converted to `bool`. That `bool` will be `false` if the `int` is 0, and will be `true` for any other value.