# Bitwise operations | And | Which situation is true or false in c#

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I show my question by an example :

```
    int a = 1 << 0; // = 1
    int flag = 1;
    bool b = flag & a; // = 1 < In c++ this line has no error but in c# error is like this :
```

> Cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

1. When `b` variable is **true** and when `b` variable is **false** in c#?
2. How fix the error?
3. When does c++ recognize that `b` variable is true? The other side should be `(flag & a) != 0` or `(flag & a) == 1` or something else?

Comment: Not really sure about your question, you can't compile every c++ code in C#.

Comment: as much as I know, C++ assumes 1 to be true. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725044/can-i-assume-booltrue-int1-for-any-c-compiler

Comment: @Habib To be complete, C++ considers 0 to be `false` and every other value to be `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you write it like so:

```
bool b = (flag & a) != 0;
```

You can't assign an int to a bool in C#, like you can in C++.

(In C++ the compiler generates code that effectively does the same as the code above, although most C++ compilers will generate a warning if you just try to assign an int to a bool.)

Also [see the Visual C++ warning C4800](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx), which tells you to write it this way in C++ too.

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++, `false` is `0`, and `true` is non-zero (`!0`). C++ treats every value as boolean (as in, any value can be tested for its truth-iness).

In C#, the types are better enforced, so you can't simply test a number for truthiness.

You'd have to equate the resulting expression to something:

```
bool b = (flag & a) != 0;
```