# Working on bitwise operators - And + LeftShift - A reverse calculate

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

Take a look at these codes :

```
    const int a = 1 << 0;  // = 1
    const int b = 1 << 1;  // = 2
    const int c = 1 << 2;  // = 4
    const int d = 1 << 3;  // = 8

    int flag = 15;  // = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8

    int e1 = flag & a;  // = 1
    int e2 = flag & b;  // = 2
    int e3 = flag & c;  // = 4
    int e4 = flag & d;  // = 8

    bool b1 = e1 != 0;  // = true
    bool b2 = e2 != 0;  // = true
    bool b3 = e3 != 0;  // = true
    bool b4 = e4 != 0;  // = true
```

Upper Codes in other way(simpler) :

```
    const int a = 1 << 0;  // = 1
    const int b = 1 << 1;  // = 2
    const int c = 1 << 2;  // = 4
    const int d = 1 << 3;  // = 8

    int flag = 15;  // = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8

    bool b1 = (flag & a) != 0;  // = true
    bool b2 = (flag & b) != 0;  // = true
    bool b3 = (flag & c) != 0;  // = true
    bool b4 = (flag & d) != 0;  // = true
```

I need a **Reverse Formula** to return `flag` value when we set :
**b1 , b2 , b3 , b4** variables and make them constant.

So we have `2*2*2*2 = 16` different situations. mean `(true|flase)*(true|flase)*(true|flase)*(true|flase) = 16` for setting `b` variables.

With which method we can figure out what should `flag` be?

Mean :

```
    const int a = 1 << 0;  // = 1
    const int b = 1 << 1;  // = 2
    const int c = 1 << 2;  // = 4
    const int d = 1 << 3;  // = 8

    int flag = ?;

    bool b1 = (? & a) != 0;  // = true > I WANT b1 True
    bool b2 = (? & b) != 0;  // = false > I WANT b2 False
    bool b3 = (? & c) != 0;  // = true > I WANT b3 True
    bool b4 = (? & d) != 0;  // = false > I WANT b4 False
```

For example i want `b1 True , b2 False , b3 True , b4 False`. So What is the flag?
Or
I want  `b1 False, b2 False , b3 True , b4 False`. So What is the flag?
How did you find it and give me a method to calculate it!

---

In my example `flag` is 15 (sum of a+b+c+d) and in this way all `b` variables are true.

---

Related:  [Bitwise operations | And | Which situation is true or false in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422758/bitwise-operations-and-which-situation-is-true-or-false#37422967)

Comment: What is different than your deleted question?

Comment: 5 and 4 respectively, but you already showed how to calculate it so why is this a question?

Comment: [Asking the same question again, but with different words](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303253/asking-the-same-question-again-but-with-different-words)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `flag` variable using bitwise-or (`|`) operations with the values you want to be set:

if you want `b1` and `b4` be `true` and `b2` y `b3` be `false`:

```
int flag = a | d; 

bool b1 = (flag & a) != 0;  // = true
bool b2 = (flag & b) != 0;  // = false
bool b3 = (flag & c) != 0;  // = false
bool b4 = (flag & d) != 0;  // = true
```

If you want only `b3` to be `true`:

```
int flag = c; 

bool b1 = (flag & a) != 0;  // = false
bool b2 = (flag & b) != 0;  // = false
bool b3 = (flag & c) != 0;  // = true
bool b4 = (flag & d) != 0;  // = false
```

If you have `b`s values and want the flag:

```
int flag = (b1 ? a : 0) | (b2 ? b : 0) | (b3 ? c : 0) | (b4 ? d : 0);
```