# Logical OR operand evaluation basics in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C basics and I'm trying to understand why the output of this example is `1 2 1 1`:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    a = b = c = d = 1;
    a = ++b > 1 || ++c > 1 && ++d > 1;
    printf("%d%d%d%d", a, b, c, d);
}
```

- As far as I understand, only the left operand before Logical OR `||` is getting evaluated because it is True and there is no need to evaluate the right one. The right operand is not evaluated. Is this right?
- The left operand is true because `++b > 1` equals `1` (2 is larger than 1) and `a = 1`. Right?

Comment: Yes, both points are correct.

Comment: For future reference, the term you are looking for is "short circuiting".

Comment: The left side of the `||` evaluates to true, and therefore the right side does not need to be evaluated.  Hence, `c` and `d` remain `1`, `b` is `2`, and `a` gets assigned to true, which is `1`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, now *that* should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left side of the `||` evaluates to `true`, and therefore the right side does not need to be evaluated. Hence, `c` and `d` remain `1`, `b` is incremented to `2`, and `a` gets assigned to `true`, which is promoted to `1`.

**Explanation:**

```
a = b = c = d = 1;
```

All four variables equal `1`.

```
a = ++b > 1
```

The variable `b` gets incremented to `2` *before* the rest of the RHS gets evaluated.  This results in the expression `2 > 1`, which is true.  As others have mentioned, your `||` expression is then *short-circuited*, which means that what follows the `||` will not be evaluated because the program already knows that the entire RHS will be true regardless of what happens.  This is why I did not bother to even write the expression `++c > 1 && ++d > 1`, because it will be skipped.

And the variable `a` is set to true, which is the same as `1`.

Reference on promoting true to `int`: [Can I assume (bool)true == (int)1 for any C++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725044/can-i-assume-booltrue-int1-for-any-c-compiler)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right on both accounts.

The important to note is that this behaviour is guaranteed by the C standard and is commonly known as [*short circuting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Relevant: [Is short-circuiting logical operators mandated? And evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628526/is-short-circuiting-boolean-operators-mandated-in-c-c-and-evaluation-order)

Answer (score 1):

The first line `a = b = c = d = 1` assigns 1 to all variables as the associativity of the assignment operator (=) is from right to left.

Next:
The concept to be applied here is called short-circuiting.
The preference of '>' is higher than all the other operators except for the increment operator(++) -- the prefix increment to be precise.

Hence, first b gets incremented to 2. Now, the comparison of `2 > 1` occurs, which is true or 1.
The left operand of the OR is true or 1. Thus, it hardly makes a difference if the right operand is true or false as the final output would still return true or 1.

Thus, everything to the right of the OR (||) isn't even evaluated. So c and d are not incremented and remain = 1.

a = True or 1
Thus `a = 1, b = 2, c = d = 1`

Answer (score 0):

OR operator in c is the Logical operator. || Logical OR. True only if either one operand is true. In first line you assign 1 to all variables by `a=b=c=d=1`.
After that, you are comparing conditions that `a=++b>1` if it is true then the compiler will check the second condition that `++c>1 && ++d>1` this is with the && AND operator so in this if both equations are correct only then the command will run.