# c: What does this line do?

Tags: c, addition, operator-precedence, compound-assignment, relational-operators

I read some code and came over this rather cryptic syntax:

```
size_t count = 1;
char *s         = "hello you";
char *last_word = "there";

count += last_word < (s + strlen(s) - 1); #line of interest
```

Count is incremented, somehow. But I thought the < operator would return true or false.
What does this line do?

Comment: `last_word < (s + strlen(s) - 1);` evaluates to either 1 or 0 (true or false)

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725044/can-i-assume-booltrue-int1-for-any-c-compiler) for some discussion about casting  boolean to int

Comment: @EuanSmith how is that relevant here? relational operators return the result of type `int`. From where boolean comes into picture?

Comment: Of course you are right in C.  I had forgotten that C does not have a native boolean type - spent too long in C++ and C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [operator precedance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) table, `<` binds higher than `+=` operator, so your code is essentially

```
 count += ( last_word < (s + strlen(s) - 1)) ;
```

where, the `(A < B)` evaluates to either 0 or 1 <sup>Note</sup>, so, finally, it reduces to

```
count += 0;
```

or

```
count += 1;
```

***Note:*** related to the "`1` or `0`" part, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.8/p6, *Relational operators*

> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and `>=`
>   (greater than or equal to) shall yield `1` if the specified relation is `true` and `0` if it is
>   `false`.<sup>107)</sup> The result has type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, *relational operators* always yield 0 or 1. So, this statement

```
count += last_word < (s + strlen(s) - 1);
```

adds either 0 or 1 to `count` depending on the comparison's result. It can be written as (and equivalent to):

```
if (last_word < (s + strlen(s) - 1)) {
   count = count + 1;
} else {
   count = count + 0;
}
```

(The `else` part is needless; added for explanatory purpose.)

**C11 (draft N1548.pdf), Relational operators, §6.5.8, 6**

> Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than
>   or equal to), and >= (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. 107) The result has
>   type int.

Answer (score 0):

In C there is a the `stdbool.h` header which defines as true and false. Essentially you can think of the basic implemantation as:

```
#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

`true` and `false` are defined as not zero and equal to zero respectively. So basically when `last_word < (s + strlen(s) - 1)`, count is incremented by one.

Comment: Surprise!! C has boolean.

Comment: @SouravGhosh do you mean the `stdbool` header?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. :)

Comment: Since C99 there also is a `_Bool` type you can use without using the `stdbool` header.