# Converting bool to bit in bitfield

Tags: c++

I have a bitfield:

```
struct MyBitfield {
  unsigned char field1: 1;
  unsigned char field2: 1;
};
```

These bitfield arguments are 1 bit wide and represent boolean values. I was wondering if it is valid to initialize it with `bools` as follows

```
MyBitfield my_bitfield = {true, false};
```

My question is whether this behavior is well defined. IIUC, `false` always evaluates to `0` but `true` can evaluate to any non-zero integer. If it happens to evaluate to an integer whose LSB is `0`, will it be cast to the bit `0` and evaluate to `false` or does the language guarantee that it will always be cast to the bit `1`?

Comment: `true` evalutes to `true`  , if you convert to integer you get `1` .

Comment: Oh, cool, I guess I got confused with the fact that all non-0 integers cast to true.

Comment: If you want to manipulate bit and not byte, i suggest using [bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

Comment: Clonk@, with bitsets you lose the ability to name the bits. I think this makes it less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : Yes, the language guarantee that it will always be cast to the bit 1.

Long answer :

There is some good information here :
[Can I assume (bool)true == (int)1 for any C++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725044/can-i-assume-booltrue-int1-for-any-c-compiler)

> If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and
>   the value true is converted to one.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bool_literal :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << true << '\n'
            << false << '\n'
            << std::noboolalpha
            << true << '\n'
            << false << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
1
0
```

So yes, the language guarantee that it will always be cast to the bit 1.

Answer (score 1):

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) we can read:

> If the source type is bool, the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted to the value one of the destination type (note that if the destination type is int, this is an integer promotion, not an integer conversion).

Your code is ok.

Answer (score 0):

From the current draft [n4750](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4750.pdf):

**§12.2.4/3**

> [...] A bool value can successfully be stored in a bit-field of any nonzero size. [...]

Also valid for C++03 **§9.6/3**.