# Is bool required in C++ to be represented with 1 bit set when true/ 0 bits set when false

Tags: c++, boolean, language-lawyer

I was thinking about microoptimizing a function that returns 4 bools by using an union of uint32_t and bool[4], and then doing the popcnt instruction to see how many elements of the bool array are true.

But I do not know if the standard guarantees that bool is represented as number with only 1 bit set when true and 0 bits set when it is false.

If the answer is no then I have a follow up question: if it is not required is it required that representation is constant, e.g. if I have a test that checks that true bool casted to uint_8t is 1(and 0 for false) does that this means that every representation of bools in the program will behave the same.

note: I know that it is not required that bool is 1byte, but I can static_assert on that.

Comment: *I was thinking about microoptimizing a function that returns 4 bools by using an union of uint32_t and bool[4], and then doing the popcnt instruction to see how many elements of the bool array are true.* Why not just use a `std::bitset`?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725044/can-i-assume-booltrue-int1-for-any-c-compiler

Comment: In C++ it's not allowed to use unions for type-punning, it breaks strict aliasing.

Comment: [basic](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic) `Type bool is a distinct type that has the same object representation, value representation, and alignment requirements as an implementation-defined unsigned integer type.
The values of type bool are true and false.` - I think from that it's totally implementation defined if it has 1 bit set or any (if any) number of bits set.

Comment: Casting does not provide any information. The booleans convert to 1 (`true`) and 0 (`false`), but these conversions are independent of the actual representation of the booleans.

Comment: @KamilCuk -- it's not implementation-defined. It's unspecified. In the standard, implementation-defined means that the implementation must specify what it does.

Comment: Some compilers do exceedingly weird things with invalid `bool`s, so I wouldn't try anything clever. Take a look at the "Unitialized Scalar" and "Invalid Scalar" examples here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 9):

> I was thinking about microoptimizing a function that returns 4 bools
>   by using an union of uint32_t and bool[4], and then doing the popcnt
>   instruction to see how many elements of the bool array are true.

That will cause undefined behavior because accessing an inactive member of the union violates the object lifetime rules.  You probably want to use a [`std::bitset<4>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead — it is designed for usage like this.

Note that `std::bitset` cannot directly be constructed from several `bool`s, you may have to compose an `unsigned long long` first.  Or you can use a helper function like this:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::bitset<N> pack_bools(const bool (&arr)[N])
{
    static_assert(N <= std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::digits);

    unsigned long long num{0};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (arr[i])
            num += 1LL << i;
    }
    return std::bitset<N>{num};
}
```

usage:

```
pack_bools({true, false, true, false}); // for example
```

([test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UkVTKFB8Seqilx7W))

> But I do not know if the standard guarantees that bool is represented
>   as number with only 1 bit set when true and 0 bits set when it is
>   false.

No, there's no guarantee like that.  [[basic.fundamental]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#10):

> > Type `bool` is a distinct type that has the same object
> >     representation, value representation, and alignment requirements as an
> >     implementation-defined unsigned integer type. The values of type
> >     `bool` are `true` and `false`. [ *Note:* There are no `signed`,
> >     `unsigned`, `short`, or `long` `bool` types or values. — *end
> >     note* ]

There's no more guarantee about the value representation.

> If the answer is no then I have a follow up question: if it is not
>   required is it required that representation is constant, e.g. if I
>   have a test that checks that true bool casted to uint_8t is 1(and 0
>   for false) does that this means that every representation of bools in
>   the program will behave the same.

No, there's no such guarantee either.

Comment: I am not sure about violating object lifetime rules since both members of the union are POD, but I could be wrong since often my intuition is wrong, and stuff that is *obviously* ok to me is actually UB.

Comment: "There's nothing more than that." is somewhat incorrect: conversions to and from e.g. pointer types and other integer types are also defined (i.e. 0/null/nullptr converts to `false` and the rest converts to `true`). Granted, this only specifies type value conversions, not underlying representation.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl POD isn't really that important when it comes to lifetime rules.  And yes, sometimes what we all assume is well defined is not :)

Comment: iirc talk about object lifetimes from cppcon by some google guy says we can use pods uninitialized, but maybe it is not guaranteed that they contain nonjunk value... but again C++ is very complicated and I do not want to argue about this since it is not the main question and  I am pretty sure you are right. :)